# Understanding of ggplot for histograms in R

Tags: r, math, ggplot2, histogram

I'm using the `ggplot2` package to create some histograms in R. I just want to check I'm understanding the syntax/arguments correctly. Code below.

```
ggplot(data=q2_table, aes(q2_table$some_column)) + 
geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 500, by = 2), 
col="black", 
fill="grey", 
alpha = .2) + 
labs(title="Histogram for Distribution of Some Column") +
labs(x="Days Binned", y="Count") + 
xlim(c(0,300)) + 
ylim(c(0,100000))
```

It is my understanding that:

- I'm selecting a column called "some_column" from table "q2_table"
- The min/max values in this column are 0 and 500 respectively
- Bars are grey, outline is black
- Title is "Histogram for Distribution of Some Column"
- x and y labels are "Days Binned" and "Count" respectively
- Limit of x-axis is 300
- Limit of y-axis is 100,000

Assuming the above is correct, my questions are as follows;

- What is the "by = 2" argument doing?
  `geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 500, by = 2)`,
- What does "alpha =.2" relate to?
  `alpha = .2)+`
- Is there a relationship between `geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 500, by = 2)` and `xlim(c(0,300))` such that the size of the last bin will essentially be 300+ ?
  Put another way, is `xlim(c(0,300))` a way of determining bin size, based upon the min/max values as defined in `geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 500, by = 2),`

Histogram below for illustration.

[image]

Comment: do ?seq , when you use seq, you give a value from which in your case is 0 to 500 , by 2 intervals.I guess the alpha is the transparent points,xlim is to set the x-axis. of course there is a relationship between them. if you have 100 values and set your xlim to 20, then it will only show 20 values

Comment: if you don't like to use ? or help to understand what a ggplot does, have a look at this page http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/ggplot2.html most of your doubt are addressed here

Comment: Thanks @Learner , I guess I'm struggling to understand how the actual binning works. I'm used to doing this in Excel where I'd define my own bins as say 0-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20 etc.

Comment: I understand, if you want to set your bins differently then this is done using **breaks= c(0:5,6:10,11:15, 16:20)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:** What is the "by = 2" argument doing?

**Answer 1:** "By = 2" means that the bars are created in the interval of 2

**Question 2:** What does "alpha =.2" relate to?

**Answer 2:** This relates to the opacity of the graph, alpha = 1 means solid color and alpha = 0 means absolute transparent. So alpha = 0.2 has been used to lighten the bars shade.

**Question 3:** Is there a relationship between geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 500, by = 2) and xlim(c(0,300)) such that the size of the last bin will essentially be 300+ ? Put another way, is xlim(c(0,300)) a way of determining bin size, based upon the min/max values as defined in geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 500, by = 2)?

**Answer 3:** Yes there is a relationship between the two. It is just the first one set the range and the second one has to be defined with in that range.

Let me know if you have not understood anything. I would be more than happy to help :)